# How to attach an attachment in the logstash output email?

Tags: email, logstash

In the guide format , they said the attachment is using array.
However after the format and it seems the email has been sent but no attachment in it.

Do anyone know how to use the attachment option in logstash email output??

```
output {
if "shouldmail" in [tags] {
email {
  to => 'technical@example.com'
  from => 'monitor@example.com'
  subject => 'Alert - %{title}'
 body => "Tags: %{tags}\\n\\Content:\\n%{message}"
 template_file => "/tmp/email_template.mustache"
 domain => 'mail.example.com'
 attachment => ["C:\picture.jpg"]
 port => 25
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attachment use attachments

```
output {
if "shouldmail" in [tags] {
email {
  to => 'technical@example.com'
  from => 'monitor@example.com'
  subject => 'Alert - %{title}'
 body => "Tags: %{tags}\\n\\Content:\\n%{message}"
 template_file => "/tmp/email_template.mustache"
 domain => 'mail.example.com'
 attachments => ["C:\picture.jpg"]
 port => 25
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I use the above example, but the email received still do not have any attachments in the email. Do the array need to give other elements except the file path?